# Search > Find Memberships: Difference between Membership Status Current AND Current Member?

Tags: advanced-search

Search > Find Memberships -or- Search > Advanced Search and I use the Membership criteria in my search I usually set the Membership Status to *Current* but I just noticed today below the Status field there is a radio button fieldset with a label *Current Member?*

What is the difference between the Status = Current and the fieldset for Current Member? being checked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a setting in each MEmbership Status where you decide if a Status should be considered 'current' or not.

```
Current Membership? 
Should this status be considered a current membership in good standing.     
EXAMPLE: New, Current and Grace could all be considered 'current'.
```

It is confusing that 'current' is used in two different ways.

Comment: Agreed its confusing - I have used a word replacement of "Active Member?" for "Current Member?" to avoid confusing users.

Comment: Good plan - if others were persuaded we could try pushing this through as a change to core.

Comment: https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/kpk8wf3s4iyejrwmy9nd8jwzbw

Comment: I am in favour of changing the terminology. "Active Member" would work really well.

Comment: Have posted a feature request, vote on it if you want it implemented see https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1442

Comment: Thanks Peter. It is confusing isn't it. Generally my clients rename Current to Active and that's what I use for membership searches typically. I was giving a tutorial yesterday on editing smart group criteria and that's where I came upon the "Active Member?" bit. It seems redundant.